# Возникает ошибка при оформлении заказа на битрикс (вроде что то связанное с JSON)

Tags: javascript, json

Возникает ошибка при оформлении заказа на битрикс (вроде что то связанное с JSON), вот что выходит:

> ({"order":{"ERROR":{"property":["\u0421\u0432\u043e\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430 \u0022\u041c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435\u0022 - \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430 \u0432\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0430" ] } } })

Куда копать? Как можно исправить?

Comment: `({"order":{"ERROR":{"property":["Свойство заказа "Местоположение" - ошибка ввода"] } } })`

Comment: Спасибо! Буду копать